# SSD Update for Asus Zenbook UX32A

Tags: ssd, sata, zenbook

I'm looking for a new SSD replacement (to a stock Hitachi HDD) for my Asus UX32A (Core i5 modification, with 24 GB SSD, 500 GB hdd, 4 GB ram).

My choice fell on Samsung 840 EVO, but then I've scanned my system, and found that my HDD connected through SATA 2 (while my chosen SSD connects through SATA 3).

I now doubt that the speed gain from the SSD (sams has SATA3) will be great.

Maybe I'm wrong, and my Hitachi works on SATA2 cause it supports only SATA2, and SSD will be working with SATA3. How can I check it?

**Does an SATA3 SSD disk work with an SATA2 port/motherboard and if so, what are the problems or performance losses that I might expect?**

Comment: Sheesh. How many different websites did you post this on? When in doubt, swap the positions of the SSD and HDD and see if the SSD is now running on a SATA2 bus.

Comment: heh) ssd is on the board, so i have no ability to test

Comment: Do you have a different SSD or HDD that you can test with?

Comment: no( If I had them, this question would not exist.

Comment: Hi, @wingsofovnia what did you go for in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UX32A uses the HM76 Express chipset, which supports up to six SATAIII. I don't see any reason why would Asus limit the chipset's ability to work at SATAIII speeds. It could be that your build-in Hitachi is SATAII, but your chipset is definitely SATAIII